# Center Div on screen

Tags: html, css, center

```
.alert{
    color:#555;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 36px;
    margin:10px;
    min-width: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
}
```

How would I go about centering this on the screen without using a set starting width?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to center the element. In your case apply the following css:

```
.alert{
/*add this rules*/
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
/*upto this*/
  color:#555;
  border-radius:10px;
  font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 36px;
  margin:10px;
  min-width: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
}
```

Also, have a look at centering tricks [here](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) and [here](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

---

The link you shouldn't remember. Just google about [centering tricks](https://www.google.com.np/search?q=centering+tricks&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=07FOVMbJKOXfmgXO4oLwAw) , then you'll have a lot of articles about them. Please do a research next time before you ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it, add this:

```
.alert{
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;   
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caeth/oe0wnzj2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
```

use this code

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the alert with a parent div and set it to `text-align: center;`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert-wrap">
    <div class="alert">My Alert Message!</div>
</div>
```

Then set `.alert` to `display: inline-block;` and remove `position: fixed;`

**CSS**

```
.alert-wrap {
    text-align: center;
}

.alert {
    color:#555;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 36px;
    margin:10px;
    min-width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tahrmzLz/

Comment: This doesn't work and you've removed `position: fixed` in your jsFiddle example above.

Comment: @Danko - That was a part of the original code and I've updated my answer to remove it.  Also I've provided a working JSfiddle proving in fact my solution does work.

Comment: I think that the `position: fixed` is a requirement of his CSS since it's an alert box and the OP would want it to always appear at the top and in that case your code won't work.

Comment: That is your own assumption.  I answer the question based on his own words "How would I go about centering this on the screen without using a set starting width?".  For this, my solution answers the question and it works as proven with the JSfiddle.

Comment: Also, there are several other ways to do this.  My solution is one of many that works.  It's up to the O.P. to decide whether or not the working answers fit the requirement of his or her project.